# How to insert data 'Radio Button' on Laravel?

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

i am new on laravel and i will make input using radio button . my input all = radio button . its because the input is question answer and i need input that to database like this

Table : Pemeriksaan

```
{'its the question1':'nice','its the question2':'bad'}
```

i need and want to make like this but i can't do this . i make a view like that

```
<form class="form-group" action="/user" method="post">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody><tr>
      <th style="width: 10px">#</th>
      <th>Pertanyaan</th>
      <th style="width: 60px">Tidak Baik</th>
      <th style="width: 60px">Baik</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1.</td>
      <td>Periksa kondisi kelistrikan dan kabel ,pastikan tidak ada yang terkelupas</td>
      
      <td>
          <label><input type="radio" id='1' name="input1" value="false" checked></label>
      </td>
      <td>
          <label><input type="radio" id='2' name="input1" value="true"></label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2.</td>
      <td>Periksa kondisi kabel dan tempat sambungan</td>
      
          <td>
              <label><input type="radio" id='1' name="input2" checked></label>
          </td>
          <td>
              <label><input type="radio" id='2' name="input2"></label>
          </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3.</td>
      <td>Periksa kondisi pencetakan (tinta dan kertas printer) </td>
      <td>
          <label><input type="radio" id='1' name="input3" checked></label>
      </td>
      <td>
          <label><input type="radio" id='2' name="input3"></label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4.</td>
      <td>Fix and squish bugs</td>
      <td>
          <label><input type="radio" id='1' name="input4" checked></label>
      </td>
      <td>
          <label><input type="radio" id='2' name="input4"></label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    
            
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    
  </tbody>
 
</table>
      <div class="box-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="name" value="post">Submit</button>
       </div>
</form>
```

i don't know this 'action' is right or wrong .

and this is my controller :

## edit . before , i run artisan make:contoller user --resource

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $pemeliharaan = new user;

    $pemeliharaan = user::create($request->all());
    dd($pemeliharaan);

}
```

but its nothing happened , can someone corrected about my wrong ?

my die dump

```
 View {#251 ▼
  #factory: Factory {#112 ▶}
  #engine: CompilerEngine {#256 ▼
    #compiler: BladeCompiler {#259 ▼
      #extensions: []
      #customDirectives: []
      #conditions: []
      #path: null
      #compilers: array:4 [▼
        0 => "Comments"
        1 => "Extensions"
        2 => "Statements"
        3 => "Echos"
      ]
      #rawTags: array:2 [▼
        0 => "{!!"
        1 => "!!}"
      ]
      #contentTags: array:2 [▼
        0 => "{{"
        1 => "}}"
      ]
      #escapedTags: array:2 [▼
        0 => "{{{"
        1 => "}}}"
      ]
      #echoFormat: "e(%s)"
      #footer: []
      #rawBlocks: []
      #files: Filesystem {#111}
      #cachePath: "/var/www/html/new/storage/framework/views"
      #firstCaseInSwitch: true
      -encodingOptions: 15
      #lastSection: null
      #forElseCounter: 0
    }
    #lastCompiled: []
  }
  #view: "users.create"
  #data: []
  #path: "/var/www/html/new/resources/views/users/create.blade.php"
}
```

Comment: try to do dd($request->all()); instead of dd response from function 'create' first

Comment: Are you creating user? in given snippet you used user model! Please share your table structure and in your any input there is no value attribute!

Comment: user controller u mean ?

Comment: your form didn't send any data also what the significance of this line "$pemeliharaan = new user;"

Answer (score 0):

I think you should route on route/web.php in case you are using api then route/api.php. Otherwise most simple solution would be

```
open project root in terminal/command prompt >> type php:artisan route:list <Enter>>
```

This will show all available route with their corresponding Controller and action.

After getting method if you want to just interested in knowing request data then write  on first line of function.
    dd($request->all());

Note: please make sure you send csrf_token

Comment: i have so many route list . in first i run php artisan make:controller user --resource

Comment: you need i make a new route for this input ?

Comment: i send csrf_token , you can look at my blade.php

Comment: are you sure about `new user` generally its `new User`

Answer (score 0):

try $request->input('name of input') on your controller

Comment: i meant get your properties one by one for example
$user->name = $request->input('name');
---
$user->save();